# How to operate inside two variables in C const struct?

Tags: c

There is any way to multiply two const values in c language const structs ?

example:

```
    typedef struct
    {  
        uint16_t column;
        uint16_t line;
        uint16_t full_string_screen_char_number;    
    }font_type_t;     
    
    
    const font_type_t arial_32x24_def =
    {
        .column = 13,
        .line = 7,
        .full_string_screen_char_number = (.column) * (.line),  // 91    
    };
```

The compiler show an error ( error: expected expression before '.' token ).

compiler: xc16 v2.10 (gcc based)

Comment: Aside: seems redundant to me - how about a function instead?

Comment: No, you can't reference other fields of the struct that's being created.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it is const, not variable.

Comment: XY problem. If you need to generate a struct where one of the members is set dependent on two of the others, you should write a function which takes those two pieces of data and calculates the third member, then creates the struct accordingly.

Comment: @Chris  it is const, not variable.

Comment: If you want to rely on unspecified behavior then you can do `(arial_32x24_def.column) * (arial_32x24_def.line)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't usefully reference other struct members in the initialization list.

You could do this with a macro.

```
#define FONT_DECL(VAR, COLUMN, LINE) \
const font_type_t VAR = { \
    .column = COLUMN, \
    .line = LINE, \
    .full_string_screen_char_number = ((COLUMN) * (LINE)) \
}

FONT_DECL(arial_32x24_def, 13, 7);
```

Comment: Re “You can't reference other struct members in the initialization list”: You can by using the name of the structure, which is in scope from the end of its declarator. However, the order of evaluation of the initializers is unspecified.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But don't the values have to be constant expressions? I guess it depends on whether this is a global declaration (which I was assuming) or in a function.

Comment: Re “But don't the values have to be constant expressions?”: Not if the object has automatic storage duration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As I said, I was assuming static

Comment: Anyway, I've added a qualifier. Since the evaluation order is unspecified, you can't usefully refer to them (except in expressions that ignore the value, e.g. `sizeof` and `&`).

Comment: @EricPostpischil If you DVed because of my "you can't" statement, can you undo now that I updated it? Is there some other problem with my answer?

Comment: I voted up, not down.

Answer (score 1):

In the initializers, you can refer to the members of the structure by using the name of the object:

```
const font_type_t arial_32x24_def =
    {
        .column = 13,
        .line = 7,
        .full_string_screen_char_number = arial_32x24_def.column * arial_32x24_def.line    
    };
```

However, this is not usable code because C 2018 6.7.9 23 says the evaluation order is unspecified:

> The evaluations of the initialization list expressions are indeterminately sequenced with respect to one another and thus the order in which any side effects occur is unspecified.

You should write the code so that the initial values depend on some common prior values rather than on other members of the structure.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of this answer is. It corrects the syntax error, but it still doesn't do what the OP wants because of the caveat you quote.

Comment: @Barmar: It answers the question “There is any way to multiply two const values in c language const structs ?” (no) and further tells OP they need to write their code to use prior values. That is suffixes to explain the concepts, which is what Stack Overflow is for. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.